# Logstash unable to start when I add grep filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I have a logstash instance deployed on my local and I am trying to get head wrapped around it. I added a simple grep filter to the logstash.conf file, but when I restart the service, it fails. And when I remove the grep statement it works fine. Here is my config. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
input {
        kafka {
        zk_connect => "localhost:9091"
        topic_id => "rawlog"
        reset_beginning => false
        consumer_threads => 1
        consumer_restart_on_error => true
        consumer_restart_sleep_ms => 100
        decorate_events => false
    }

}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    bind_host => "localhost"
    protocol => "http"
  }
}
filter {
  grep {
    match => {"message"=>"hello-world"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep{} is deprecated in favor of conditionals and drop{}:

```
filter {
  if [message] !~ /hello-world/ {
    drop{}
  }
}
```

If that doesn't help, post a sample of your input.

Comment: Thanks @Alain. This worked. One correction I had to make was, instead of if message, I used if [message]. Appreciate your help.